# Inheritance - Can base class functions allocate derived class data?

Tags: matlab, class, oop, inheritance

Please be gentle with this retired hardware engineer as he learns about Matlab Object Oriented programming.

I have multiple needs for a binary tree class with a bunch of special functions for walking, pruning, adding to, rewiring a simple binary tree. I've written my own class (classdef btree3 < handle) with about 20 methods, tested them and it's all working nicely so far.

Next I wrote a specific class for one use of the tree which inherits the binary tree (classdef EqTree < btree3). In general, this works in that all the btree3 methods are callable from an EqTree object:

```
X3 = EqTree;
X3.GenerateRandomTree(50,8);
X3.RenumberTree(100);
disp('Walking X3 tree');
X3.WalkTree;
```

The problem I'm having is while X3 has the EqTree data Properties in it, none of the nodes further down in the tree have them. All lower nodes are allocated as btree3 objects as (I assume) that by default that's all the btree3 methods know how to do even though it's being called for an EqTree object. Shown here are what each object looks like if it's complete:

```
>> Z1=btree3

Z1 = 

  btree3 with properties:

    NodeNum: []
       Prev: [0×0 btree3]
       Left: [0×0 btree3]
      Right: [0×0 btree3]

>> Z2=EqTree

Z2 = 

  EqTree with properties:

      Operator: []
      LeafData: []
        NodeEq: []
    NodeEqName: []
    OutputType: []
       NodeNum: []
          Prev: [0×0 btree3]
          Left: [0×0 btree3]
         Right: [0×0 btree3]

>>
```

My question: Is there a way to tell the inherited method within btree3 that allocates the nodes of the tree to also allocate the data Properties from the derived class? For instance, in the random tree created in the call above I see this:

X3 =

EqTree with properties:

```
  Operator: []
  LeafData: []
    NodeEq: []
NodeEqName: []
OutputType: []
   NodeNum: 100
      Prev: [0×0 btree3]
      Left: [1×1 btree3]
     Right: [1×1 btree3]
```

> > X3.Left

ans =

btree3 with properties:

```
NodeNum: 101
   Prev: [1×1 EqTree]
   Left: [0×0 btree3]
  Right: [0×0 btree3]
```

> > 

where there are two problems:

1) The EqTree date is not allocated down in the tree, and

2) The pointers are no longer homogenous and the methods inherited from btree3 fail when walking up the tree and find an EqTree object at the root.

If need be I can allocated the trees as btree3 objects and then populate the data with EqTree data (if the EqTree class stands alone).

I hope the question is clear enough but can post more code if necessary.

Thanks!

Re: EqTree constructor: EqTree gets allocated and, if provided, the NodeNum field from btree3 is set:

```
classdef EqTree < btree3
    properties(SetAccess = private)
        Operator    % Logic, math or function
        LeafData    % Timetable or fixed values
        NodeEq      % Equation node represents
        NodeEqName  % Name that is used in higher equations
        OutputType  % Float, Integer, timetable, boolean, etc.
    end

    methods
        function ThisNode = EqTree(NodeNum)
            if (nargin > 0)
                ThisNode.NodeNum = NodeNum;
            end
        end
```

Re: btree3 class method for adding nodes:

To try and be extra clear, the btree3 method GenerateRandomTree used above calls other methods in btree3 to actually allocate new members to the tree. When adding to the left side of the tree btree3 calls the AddNodeLeft method which, being part of the btree3 class only knows to allocate a new btree3 object. All of this works when inherited and called by the EqTree class, but the new objects are btree3 objects, not EqTree objects. I'm hoping to understand how to allocate the derived class objects here:

```
function AddNodeLeft(ThisNode, newNodeNum)
% Add newNode on left after ThisNode.
    if ThisNode.Left.exists
        error('addNodeLeft: Left side in use')
    end
    newNode = btree3(newNodeNum);
    newNode.Prev = ThisNode;
    ThisNode.Left = newNode;
end
```

Comment: My guess is you haven't implemented a new constructor method for the EqTree class? If you have, could you post it?

Comment: Well, I intended to but maybe it's not done correctly? I don't seem to be able to post code in this comment so I'll add it into the original post.

Comment: I do note however that while Z1=EqTree works Z2=EqTree(100) doesn't as it's telling me I 'cannot set the read-only property 'NodeNum of EqTree, so the btree3 object is allocated but I probably need a method for setting NodeNum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This documentation on class constructor methods](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/class-constructor-methods.html) should help guide you, along with this [doubly-linked list example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/example--implementing-linked-lists.html#responsive_offcanvas). I'm guessing that the constructor for `btree3` initializes `NodeNum`, `Prev`, `Left`, and `Right`. As such, your `EqTree` constructor should probably look something like this:

```
function ThisNode = EqTree(NodeNum)
    args = {};
    if (nargin > 0)
        args = {NodeNum};
    end
    ThisNode = ThisNode@btree3(args{:});
    % Other initializations specific to EqTree objects
end
```

You may need to reinitialize `Prev`, `Left`, and `Right` in here as well, so that they are [empty](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/empty.html) `EqTree` objects (i.e. `ThisNode.Prev = EqTree.empty;`).

With respect to other methods like `AddNodeLeft`, which create objects of the given class, you could follow the pattern in the [linked-list example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/example--implementing-linked-lists.html#responsive_offcanvas) and rewrite your methods to *accept* an object of a given class rather than *create* one internally:

```
function AddNodeLeft(ThisNode, newNode)
% Add newNode on left after ThisNode.
    if ThisNode.Left.exists
        error('addNodeLeft: Left side in use')
    end
    % Probably also want to check that ThisNode and newNode are the same class!
    newNode.Prev = ThisNode;
    ThisNode.Left = newNode;
end
```

And then call it like so:

```
ThisNode.AddNodeLeft(EqTree(newNodeNum));
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually used the double-linked list example to do the initial construction but (if it's in there) I didn't grasp any special aspects I needed to understand if my class was going to be inherited so I'll review for that. As for the ideas in your suggestion that's so far above my pay grade it will likely take me a few days to better understand it but your guess about btree3 initialization is spot on so I suspect your suggestions about how to address this issue likely are too. Give me a few days to internalize and edit. Thanks!

Comment: @LGTrader: Yeah, that linked list example simply inherited from the handle class, so it didn't really give much insight into subclass/superclass constructor issues. The first link should help with that. Good luck!

Comment: I'm going to mark this solved, although really proving it to myself is, due to my remedial programming skills, likely to take too much time. However I will keep working on it. That said, what I decided to do for now, being that in my case the binary tree is the glue that holds all this stuff together, is instead of inheriting btree3 into EqTree, I'll simply put the EqTree data into a structure and store it in btree3's data for a given node.  That's a very minor change from my original proof of concept code and well within my abilities. Thanks much for all your help!